# Incompatible types in assignment for function return union of types

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

What is best way to fix mypy for such function

```py
from typing import Union

def a(b: int) -> Union[int, str]:
    if b:
        return b
    else:
        return '2'


c: int = a(1)
d: str = a(0)
```

mypy result:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int | str", variable has type "int")  [assignment]
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int | str", variable has type "str")  [assignment]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cast()` to enforce the actual type:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=c78a1fa8bcb79f12ee79b0cf95c93808), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoDGAhgM4wCwAUFQCYCmwURAFAEYBcmKMAlFALQA%2BLvgA%2BUMiHZUoszIw4y5ykHRgBXECiislsugBsSdaZWUq1m7QHIATNapUCUALyFSMZqhgAaJswBGHh4qVQA3OiIDAH14BDpmAj5zKABiKAhEOCgAMigEOBAkNAALfBdhb0dKGld3MmZJPxYABmDQugio2MQEmmTzdMyC3PzC4rLXYUkqIA))</sub>

```py
from typing import cast

c = cast(int, a(1))  # => int
d = cast(str, a(0))  # => str
```

Of course, this relies on *you* being correct about the new type; if you were to mess up, such a `cast()` might cost you an hour or two:

```py
e = cast(str, 42)  # fine
reveal_type(e)     # => str
```

Another way is to use `isinstance()` checks. This is safer, but more verbose:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=7560d0337974ccd042425102d8a7f622), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=CYUwZgBAhgFARgLggSwHYBcCUEC0A%2BFDCAHwgGd0AnBAWACgJGVJF6n2JKR0BXS1CHDZMQAGzIhaDDoy69%2BEAOQAmRfXqhIYHqgDG6ZAHtUAfXRQA1mgDmJtOhgA3JPYA0EAPTZ8EAHLHJYUYAOlCgiA1wCG09A2MzSxsTCkonJBT3L1wCf1RA6RCwunpdCABeaBgARkx6LkcQKFEzAE8ABxAYXWwIAGIIAFt2logAMgg2lspkawALdHKCexJyKnU6ZEhkMjQKKD1O3Xd7TClGGP0jU3MrVFt7Ltq6MQkz6J1L%2BJuklMf6IA))</sub>

```py
c = a(1)  # int | str

if isinstance(c, int):
  function_taking_int(c)
else:
  function_taking_str(c)
```